# Designing one to many relation where Many can be one of 2 entities

Tags: postgresql, relations

Apologies if this seems like a rather naive question but I'm relatively new to database design and I'm struggling to find the correct terminology to help source answers myself, so I'm turning here.

Essentially I'm designing a database which keeps track of a users investments.
Initially the user could only record investments in stocks of companies so we have the following table:

Table: Investments

- id (pk)
- numberOfShares
- userId (fk public.Users(id))
- companyId (fk public.Companies(id))

We are now introducing a new type of Equity a user can invest in 'ETFs'. The investment can either be in a Company OR and ETF but not both.

It's worth noting that there are some overlap in attributes for Company and ETFs (things like Name, Exchange, Description etc) but they both have their own unique attributes also.

Ideas I have are:

- 2 tables for company_investments & etf_investments and then create a view to Union All them together on their ID to create one table to query by the company or etf id (which we'll call an 'equity id'). All id's in both tables are uuid_v4 so should always be unique across tables & adding a type column ( `text 'company' AS type` ) in the join with the table name so know which equity the id belongs to.
- Update the existing investment table to have a 'equityType' and 'equityId' column instead of `companyId`. No foreign key on the ID but I can use the equityType (Company | Etf) value to look up the appropriate table for the equityID.

This seems like a rather common requirement and I'm worried my lack of experience and mental modal is meaning I'm reaching for concepts I already know and trying to bend them rather than being aware of better approaches. I'm greatful for any advice that can be shared.

Comment: I would consider storing companies and ETFs in the same table and perhaps distinguish them with a `type` attribute. This is a notoriously hard problem in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I had considered this, unfortunately theres only a small amount of overlap between Company and ETF entity. They'd be alot of null columns floating around, which may not be the worse thing I guess.

I've looked at the Supertype -> Subtype modal which seems rather elegant but worried its a bit overkill for what I'm trying to do: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969133/database-design-articles-blog-posts-photos-stories/4970646#4970646

Comment: If there are not lots of attributes for those entities, I would not worry too much about using a single table. NULLs don't take up storage space in PostgreSQL.